# Dimension of a variety over finite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Affine varieties, as the common zeroes of polynomials over some field, are irreducible algebraic sets and they're relatively easy to understand when polynomials are over $\Bbb C$. However, how can I determine that an algebraic set is a variety (i.e. irreducible) over a finite field $\Bbb F_q$, where q is a power of a prime. And more importantly, how to find its dimension?

For instance, in order to make everything easy, let $f=x^2+3$ and our finite field be $\Bbb F_7$. The algebraic set defined by $f$ over $\Bbb F_7$ is the set $$V= \{y\in acl(\Bbb F_7) : f(y)=0  \}$$

Therefore $2,5,9,12 \in V$, as $2^2+3 \equiv5^2+3 \equiv 9^2+3 \equiv 0 $ (mod $7$), and there are infinitely such elements in $V$. Equivalently, $V$ consists of the numbers $2$ mod $7$ and $5$ mod $7$. So, I think that $V$ is defined by union of smaller algebraic sets $x-2$ and $x-5$. So, I think that V is not a variety. But, are these smaller components of $V$ varieties? If they're so, what are their dimension? More generally, how can I find dimension of a variety defined over a finite field. For example, what is dimension of the variety defined by $x-2$ over $\Bbb F_7$ ?

Comment: 2,9 and 5,12 are the same elements modulo 7.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I mean 9, 12 as elements of algebraic closure of F_7, which is union of all finite fields with 7^n elements for each n. So, 9 as itself stays in it, i guess?

Comment: In any field of characteristic $7$ you have $2=9$ and $5=12$. In particular for any algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F}_7$.

Comment: Chiming in with others. For a different way of looking at it: You do know that $\Bbb{F}_{7^n}\cong\Bbb{F}_7[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ for any irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ of degree from $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$. In the ring $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$ we have $2=9$, so the same holds for all the quotients.

Comment: And yet another way of looking at it: The algebraic closure is *an extension* of $\Bbb{F}_7$. Meaning that the elements that are equal in $\Bbb{F}_7$ remain equal in all the extensions. For example $2/1$ and $4/2$ are the same elements in $\Bbb{Q}$, so they remain the same elements in $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$. You need to review finite fields and field extension sooner rather than later.

Comment: With a prime ideal $I = (x^2+3) k[x]$ of $k[x]$ then $V(I)$ is defined by its coordinate ring $k[x]/I$ which is of dimension $0$ because all its elements are algebraic over $k$.  

With $I = (x) k[x,y,z]$ then $V(I)$ is of dimension $2$ because every element of $k[x,y,z]/I$ is algebraic over $k[y,z]$ and they are not all algebraic over $k[t]$ for any $t \in k[x,y,z]/I$. When looking at $\Bbb{Z}$-schemes you need to replace the size of the transcendental basis by the Krull dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Your $V$ consists of the union of two zero-dimensional varieties, namely the points $y = 2$ and $y = -2$. There are many ways to define the dimension of a variety, such as the [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) (in the affine case) or the [transcendence degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) of the function field.

You can determine whether an affine variety is irreducible by checking whether its ring of functions is an integral domain.